# Coding for an SQL server in a local project

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm coding in ASP.Net on a local machine through visual studio. So when I run the code it starts an ASP.Net service for me.

So now I'm wondering how I setup an SQL server for local development purposes? I need it to have data in it constantly so that when I stop running the ASP page it doesn't just empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to install SQL Express and hook into that.  The data will persist in the db unrelated to your asp.net service:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247257%28VS.80%29.aspx